# Nginx reverse proxy is not working

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy

My setup is like this

ngnix(aws) -> tomcat server(on the same aws server)

$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)

$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

Content of /etc/nginx/conf.d/myapp.conf

```
server {
        listen      80;
        server_name myapp.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen                *:443 ;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /tmp/nginx.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /tmp/nginx.key;
        server_name           myapp.com;
        access_log            /var/log/nginx/myapp.access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/myapp.error.log;

        location / {
               proxy_pass http://localhost:8764;
        }
}
```

When I am trying to visit myapp from browser, I am getting **ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH**

Someone suggested by I should try to connect it using OpenSSL,

```
openssl s_client -connect myapp.com:443 
CONNECTED(00000003)
140211097622168:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:769:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 7 bytes and written 305 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1533215612
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Can someone suggest whats the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifiy the servername, as in:

```
openssl s_client -servername myapp.com -connect myapp.com:443
```

The one you give in the connect, gets resolved to an IP address and is never seen by the server.   So the server doesn't know what certificate to use.   I overlooked the "AWS".  The IP address you get for myapp.com may be used by hundreds or thousands of systems.